# How to access Form's Controls from Roslyn Runtime class?

Tags: c#, dynamic, runtime, roslyn

I made a Roslyn Script in order to execute it in run-time.
I mean in a during clicking of a button1 on a Form1 working process.
After this event We need to figure out how to get textBox1.Text property inside Roslyn run-time and use it for our purposes.

Anyway.....
at first we need to add 3 main references to our project called "DemoFormControlAccesInRoslyn"
this references are:

```
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp     
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis    
System.Collections.Immutable.dll
```

---

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string expresion1 = roslynExpresion;  //  it is down below

    var tree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(expresion1);
    var comp1 = CSharpCompilation1(tree);
    Diagnostics1(comp1);

    ExecuteCommand(comp1, "Method1", this);
}
private static object ExecuteCommand(CSharpCompilation comp1, string MethodName1, params object[] P)
{
    object result1 = null;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        comp1.Emit(stream);
        var assembly1 = Assembly.Load(stream.GetBuffer());
        var type1 = assembly1.GetType("RuntimeClass1");
        var greeter1 = Activator.CreateInstance(type1);
        var method1 = type1.GetMethod(MethodName1);
        try
        {
            method1.Invoke(greeter1, P);
        }
        catch (Exception ex1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex1.ToString());
        }
    }
    return result1;
}
private static CSharpCompilation CSharpCompilation1(SyntaxTree tree)
{
    var option1 = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary);
    var ref1 = new[]
    {
        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof (System.ComponentModel.Component).Assembly.Location),
        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof (object).Assembly.Location),
        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof (FileInfo).Assembly.Location),
        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof (System.Linq.Enumerable).Assembly.Location),
        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof (System.Windows.Forms.Form).Assembly.Location),


        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof (Form1).Assembly.Location)
    };
    var comp1 = CSharpCompilation.Create("DemoRoslynRuntime").WithOptions(option1).AddReferences(ref1).AddSyntaxTrees(tree);
    return comp1;
}
private static void Diagnostics1(CSharpCompilation comp1)
{
    var diag1 = comp1.GetDiagnostics();
    foreach (var d in diag1)
    {
        if (d.WarningLevel < 3)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(d.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public string roslynExpresion =
@"
  using System;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.IO;
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using DemoFormControlAccesInRoslyn;

  public class RuntimeClass1 : DemoFormControlAccesInRoslyn.Form1
  {
        public void Method1(Form1 f1)
        {
             MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);   //This will work if textBox1 has public modifier. But this will not work for dynamic!
             MessageBox.Show(f1.textBox1.Text);  //we can use this if textBox1 has public modifier.
        }
  }
"
```

Anyway...
my goal is how to solve this problem in my Roslyn script expression?
When Form1 is running and I will change the textBox1.Text from "oldText" to "newText" and when after that I will click the button1 Roslyn script will execute but it will show me MessageBox with still "oldText" string value!
Why?

Also in order to do it is it necessary to inherit RuntimeClass1 from DemoFormControlAccesInRoslyn.Form1?
Or we can simply inherit it from Form class?

It might be good if instead of (f1.textBox1.Text) we can write (textBox1.Text) inside Method1.
Please remember this is our priority.

```
public void Method1(Form1 f1)
{
    textBox1 = f1.textBox1;  
    MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);  //this will work for dynamic if textBox1 has public modifier and we will see the message with current textBox1.Text value I mean "newText" string.
}
```

Comment: Before you can have any hope at all to generate that code with Roslyn, you *first* need to have a credible version that you can write by hand.  So add a new project to your solution, add a class and write code that works.  You'll inevitably run into the practical problems, like not being able to use inheritance and having no access to private members.  Those problems have to be solved first.

Comment: You mean to add new project and then think about How to access control from Form1 on this new Form2?